# Is it possible to run 1 command in 3 different cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I just want to ask if its possible to run multiple cmd window with same command

as example i have 4 different .bat file contains something like that

```
dir *.txt > text.txt
dir *.doc > word.txt
dir *.bla > bla.txt
....
....
....
```

I want these commands  run in different windows not synchronized.

may anyone help me?

Comment: Your description is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a bat with this code :

```
@echo off 
for /l %%a in (1,1,4) do (start "Yourbat.bat")
```